Is my LED lighting circuit load calculation correct?
Am I way off in my estimations that my total load will be significantly lower than the safe amount for my setup? I have a hard time understanding how parallel lines affects load calculation and what I should consider when splicing a line.


The fact that you have branch circuits in parallel isn't really important. Almost any lighting circuit does, and it doesn't usually change load calculations. Any one leg's wire has the capacity to handle the entire circuit, as it actually does near the panel.
